# Run .animate() once after scroll trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I have a div I'd like to animate once after a certain distance has been reached between a trigger div and the top of the window, but when within a .scroll() function the animation is continually triggered as you scroll.

This below code works fine:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var a = $('.intro-text').offset().top;
   console.log(a);

   if ( a > 100 ) {
     $('.hide-me').fadeOut();
   } else if ( a < 100 ) {
     $('.hide-me').fadeIn();
   }

});
```

But if I change it to .animate(), it's continually queued up and takes forever to run:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var a = $('.intro-text').offset().top;
   console.log(a);

   if ( a > 100 ) {

     $('.hide-me').animate({
       left: -200
     }, 1000);

   } else if ( a < 100 ) {

     $('.hide-me').animate({
       left: 0
     }, 1000);

   }

});
```

My coding skills aren't the best, but I'd like it to learn if there's a function within jQuery / pure javascript before going into any external libraries or plugins. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you could try putting `.stop()` before the fadeout / fadein

Comment: You need to `debounce` the scroll event so it doesn't fire continuously (either via a plugin or via a simple `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` pair).  You might also like to check if it's already visible/hidden via a flag rather than rely on scroll position.  Or check if `:animated`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `scroll` object and save two flags `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

```
var scroll = {
          fadeIn: false,
          fadeOut: false
};
```

**Explanation**

Inside your scroll event there are two conditions `a>100` and `a<100`

So, once one of the condition is true it goes inside and check if the flag is set before triggering the animation and then sets flag of the animation done to true and clears the other flag.

**For Example:**

```
 if (a > 100) {
    if (!scroll.fadeOut) {
      $('.hide-me').fadeOut();
      scroll.fadeOut = true;
      scroll.fadeIn = false;
    }
  }
```

In the above code

It checks if `scroll.fadeOut` is not set then

It does the animation

```
 $('.hide-me').fadeOut();
```

and sets the flags

```
 scroll.fadeOut = true;
 scroll.fadeIn = false;
```

This will not allow this animation to be executed again until the second one is triggered and its clears the flag.

**Full JS**

```
var scroll = {
      fadeIn: false,
      fadeOut: false
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var a = $('.intro-text').offset().top;
  console.log(a);

  if (a > 100) {
    if (!scroll.fadeOut) {
      $('.hide-me').fadeOut();
      scroll.fadeOut = true;
      scroll.fadeIn = false;
    }
  } else if (a < 100) {
    if (!scroll.fadeIn) {
      $('.hide-me').fadeIn();
      scroll.fadeIn = true;
      scroll.fadeOut = false;
    }
  }

});
```

**UPDATE**

```
var scroll = {
  fadeIn: false,
  fadeOut: false
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var a = $('.intro-text').offset().top;
  console.log(a);

  if (a > 100) {
    if (!scroll.fadeOut) {
      $('.hide-me').animate({
        left: -200
      }, 1000);
      scroll.fadeOut = true;
      scroll.fadeIn = false;
    }
  } else if (a < 100) {
    if (!scroll.fadeIn) {
      $('.hide-me').animate({
        left: 0
      }, 1000);
      scroll.fadeIn = true;
      scroll.fadeOut = false;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but would this run similarly with .animate()?

Comment: Great! This actually worked out just as intended. Would love if you could explain what it was that's occurring within the code.

Comment: @Finnb I have added explaination check it out

Answer (score 1):

In these scenarios you can use jquery [`.stop([clearQueue],[jumpToEnd])`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) method like:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
  debounce(function() {
    var a = $('.intro-text').offset().top;
    console.log(a);
    if (a > 100) {
      $('.hide-me').stop(true, true).animate({
        left: -200
      }, 1000);
    } else if (a < 100) {
      $('.hide-me').stop(true, true).animate({
        left: 0
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, 50);
});
```

If more than one animation method is called on the same element, the later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element. These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When `.stop()` is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately. If the `clearQueue` parameter is provided with a value of `true`, then the rest of the animations in the queue are removed and never run.

Comment: This one almost works! The problem now is as you continue to scroll, it the initial animation is being canceled out, making it instantaneous. Thanks for the descriptive answer however, this will certainly become useful for me later.

Comment: You can use `debounce` function here for ensuring a given task doesn't fire so often that it bricks browser performance. Try to increase or decrease the value `50` at last as required.

Comment: Interesting. Seems a little complex, but useful for certain tasks in the future. Much appreciated.